# Amazon AWS Free Usage Tier after first year?

Tags: amazon

The whole Free Tier offer isn't totally clear to me.

For the first 12 months I get free limited use for most of the Amazon services.
But what happens after the 12 months?
Do I need to pay something if I completely stop using it by then?

I simply would like fiddle around with all this webapps stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get a year of running the equivalent of 1 micro instance for 1 years with moderate bandwidth. It used to be pretty easy to breach the limits on the EBS, but they seem to have raised that now.

After 12 months you have to pay for what you are using, but remember there's more than just turning off any instances, you have to remember to delete everything in S3 and EBS. But as long as you are careful, you don't pay anything.

Comment: What if I dont keep any balance in bank account, how they will charge me then?

Comment: The question is how does one gracefully terminate the 1-year of free AWS usage? Can't seem to find any "Cancel" option.

Comment: @ThalisKalfigkopoulos To start with, terminate the instance, deregister any AMIs, delete the volume if termination doesn't already do that, delete any snapshots and dis-associate and release any IPs. Deleting any AWS security credentials would probably make sense too.

Comment: @ThalisKalfigkopoulos The cancel option is under Billing->Account Settings->Close my account

Comment: thanks what happens if you don't delete the instances, storage or snapshots ? Do you get auto-charged to your card ?